# React setInterval with update state makes onClick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, setinterval, html5-audio

I made a custom audio player in React that updates the so called "Scrubber" of the audio file (progressbar) with the value based on duration of the player. Everything works fine except that if you press the play/pause button  when the interval updates (mousedown -> interval updates state -> mouseup) then the button click doesn't fire.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';

import VolumeButton from 'components/VolumeButton/VolumeButton.jsx';
import play from 'img/icons/play.svg';
import pause from 'img/icons/pause.svg';
import './AudioPlayer.css';

class AudioPlayer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentTime: '00:00',
            endTime: '00:00',
            intervalsInitiated: false,
            player: null,
            playing: false,
            progressBar: null
        };
        this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
    }

    initIntervals = () => {
        let intervals = setInterval(() => {
            this.updateScrubber(this.state.player.currentTime);
            this.updateTime(this.state.player.currentTime);
        }, 100);
        this.setState({
            intervals: intervals,
            intervalsInitiated: true
        });
    };

    setUpAudioTime = player => {
        console.log('setup time');
        let playerCurrentTime = player.currentTime;

        let currentTime = this.calculateTime(playerCurrentTime);
        this.setState({
            currentTime: currentTime,
            endTime: this.calculateTime(player.duration)
        });
        this.updateScrubber(playerCurrentTime);
    };

    initPlayer = () => {
        console.log('initPlayer');

        // Add resize listener for showing volume on desktop
        this.addResize();
        this.handleResize();

        // Setup correct player
        let player = new Audio(this.props.audioPath);
        let progressBar = document.querySelector('.ProgressBar');

        // Add event for audio stopped for play button
        player.addEventListener('ended', () => this.toggleAudioPlay());

        // Set state to correct player
        // TODO: Do this in update aswell going from one to another
        this.setState({
            player: player,
            progressBar: progressBar
        });
        player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () =>
            this.setUpAudioTime(player)
        );
    };

    toggleAudioPlay = () => {
        console.log('toggling audio');
        if (!this.state.player) {
            return;
        }
        !this.state.intervalsInitiated
            ? this.initIntervals()
            : this.resetComponent();
        this.state.playing
            ? this.state.player.pause()
            : this.state.player.play();
        this.setState({
            playing: !this.state.playing
        });
    };

    updateScrubber = playerCurrentTime => {
        if (!this.state.player || !this.state.progressBar) {
            return;
        }
        let prog = this.state.progressBar;
        prog.value = playerCurrentTime / this.state.player.duration;
        this.setState({
            progressBar: prog
        });
    };

    updateTime = playerCurrentTime => {
        this.setState({
            currentTime: this.calculateTime(playerCurrentTime)
        });
    };

    calculateTime = lengthInSeconds => {
        let minutes = Math.floor(lengthInSeconds / 60);
        let seconds = Math.floor(lengthInSeconds) - minutes * 60;
        let time =
            (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) +
            ':' +
            (seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);
        return time;
    };

    seek = event => {
        if (!this.state.player || !this.state.progressBar) {
            return;
        }
        let percent =
            event.nativeEvent.offsetX / this.state.progressBar.offsetWidth;
        let prog = this.state.progressBar;
        prog.value = percent;
        this.setState({ progressBar: prog });
        let newTime = percent * this.state.player.duration;
        let player = this.state.player;
        player.currentTime = newTime;
        this.setState({
            player: player
        });
        this.updateTime(newTime);
    };

    resetComponent() {
        console.log('reset component');
        clearInterval(this.state.intervals);
        this.setState({
            intervalsInitiated: false
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initPlayer();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className={`AudioPlayer ${
                    this.state.width < 800 ? 'AudioPlayer--extended' : ''
                }`}
            >
                <audio className="MarkerAudio" preload="metadata">
                    <source src={this.props.audioPath} type="audio/mp3" />
                    Your device doesnt support audio format.
                </audio>
                <div className="PlayerControls">
                    <div className="PlayButton" onClick={this.toggleAudioPlay}>
                        {this.state.playing ? (
                            <ReactSVG
                                className="AudioIcon"
                                svgStyle={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                                path={pause}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <ReactSVG
                                className="AudioIcon"
                                svgStyle={{
                                    height: '100%',
                                    left: '2px',
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    width: '100%'
                                }}
                                path={play}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <span className="CurrentTime">
                        {this.state.currentTime}
                    </span>
                    <progress
                        onClick={this.seek}
                        className="ProgressBar"
                        value="0"
                        min="0"
                        max="1"
                    />
                    <span>{this.state.endTime}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```

However, the click still works if I make sure I do a "fast-click" or if the interval isn't initiated. Any ideas on how to handle this? Should I use a onMouseDown or something instead? Or is there anyway to make sure that the interval and state change doesn't interfere with the onClick?

Comment: Could you show more of your code? I think it will be hard to say what might be wrong from the code that is currently in your question.

Comment: @Tholle I really don't think it's the code in itself. More of a state updating/onClick event but I can edit in some more parts. Give me a sec.

Comment: You might very well be right, [but there is nothing stopping the `onClick` because of a re-render in an isolated example at least](https://codesandbox.io/s/5324opro3p).

Comment: @Tholle updated. But as mentioned it really doesn't matter what the click does in itself. It works when intervals are not running. It does seems weird though.. let me see if I can copy my whole component.

Comment: @Tholle Alright so this is basically the component. I removed some unnecessary code but this should have everything needed for the actual issue.

Comment: I also noticed that the onClick on the progressbar works without issue (mousedown -> hold and wait so interval has updated -> mouseup)...

Comment: Is `toggling audio` always logged to the console, i.e. the click handler works and it's just that the `setState` is not working properly?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't even log it. Or to be more clear - it does work as expected if I do a click (mousedown and mouseup) before interval updates. Then it logs and updates just like expected. And I'm getting more confused since the seek method works without issues. Thanks for taking the time to help btw.

Comment: For example, if I change the interval to be 10 seconds the click works just as I want. However, if I click and hold, wait 10 seconds and then release mouse, nothing happens. So it's definitely something to do with the intervals updating :D

Comment: If I remove the functions inside the setInterval and instead use a console log there it also works like expected.

Comment: I don't see exactly what is causing your issue, but you are mutating the state directly and not giving a function to `setState` in many places where your update is derived from the current state. This can introduce subtle bugs. [There is more information about that here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: @Tholle I rewrote everything since I realized I can just keep player and progressBar as component variables instead. This means I no longer update state in updateScrubber. This means that if I remove the updateTime in my setInterval then everything works as expected. So the problem has to be updating state in a function that runs in a setInterval. However, since I need to update the component that shows the time I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Great that you got it working. I don't think it has to do with `setState` being called in a `setInterval`, but that you are mutating state directly and not giving `setState` a function, which may introduce race condition. Check the `setState(previousState => ...)` portion of the documentation I linked above.

Comment: Hahahaha @Tholle, since you're invested in this I finally figured it out! The icon I was using for the play button somehow bubbled BUT when the state updated that bubbling somehow disappeared. I can't frikkin believe it. Everything now works as expected. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone wondering it had something do to with click on the icon not bubbling properly when state updated. All I had to do to fix this was to add `pointer-events: none;` on the icon so the click gets triggered directly on the div and not on icon.